# What does it mean to return a reference to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I was doing some exercises on arrays, and I was prompted to return a reference to an array after copying it element by element. What does this exactly mean?

My code is the following:

```
 public static int[] cloneArray(int array[])
  {
    int[] arraycopy = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      arraycopy[i] = array[i];
    }
    return arraycopy;
  }
```

I don't know what I should be returning though as a "reference": should I return an array of ints or an int? Whenever I try to print the array, I get a weird combination of characters and numbers (unless I invoke Arrays.toString()).

Comment: To address the last sentence: yes, if you try to use `a.toString()` on an array `a`, you **will** get a weird combination of characters and numbers.  It's not an indication that anything's wrong, except that using `a.toString()` is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

"Return a reference to an array" just means "return an array".

Java only returns *values*, which are either *primitives* or object *references* (ie for objects, the *value* is a *reference*).

Although Java is based on C, it doesn't sully itself with pointers etc like C does.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, arrays and objects do not act like primitive types such as int. Consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass {
  public static int method1(int ar[]) {
    int x = ar[1];
    ar[1] = 3;
    return x;
  }
}
```

Now suppose that somewhere else, the follow code is executed:

```
int abcd[] = new int[3];
abcd[0] = 0;
abcd[1] = 1;
abcd[2] = 2;
int d = MyClass.method1(abcd);
System.out.println(abcd[1]);
```

What would be printed? It's not 1, but 3. This is because the method was not given the data in the array, it was told the location of the array. In other words, it was passed a *reference*. Because it was using a reference, changing the value of an array index changed its value in the code that called it. This would not have happened if method1 had taken an int as an argument.

Basically, in Java, methods do not accept arrays as arguments or return arrays. They only use references to arrays. The same goes for objects (except for Strings, which are passed by value).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Objects are only accessed by reference. Just return the Array object.

Comment: Not quite. Java is always pass-by-value, but in the case of objects that value is a reference.

Comment: While now wholly true, it's not the clearest wording, and is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I was trying not to digress into details which don't matter to a Java users. May have been overly terse. Shrug; Bohemian's answer is fine.